# × TypeError: _data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.storeProducts.forEach is not a function after fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]
Data exports two variables (an array with objects, and an object of a specific product)
[image]
productReducer gets the variables from Data and everything works fine. However, now you need to get data from the API through fetch.

I created two files to fetch data from the server and imported it. all data is displayed in the console but from the file into which I imported them this error pops up: TypeError:

```
_data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.storeProducts.forEach is not a function
Module../src/global-state/product.js
C:/Users/Константин/Desktop/phone-shop/shop/src/global-state/product.js:8
   5 | import { SET_PRODUCT_DETAILS } from '../actions/types';
   6 | 
   7 | let tempProducts = [];
>  8 | storeProducts.forEach(item => tempProducts.push({ ...item }));
   9 | 
  10 | const initialState = {
  11 |   products: tempProducts,
View compiled
```

looks strange because the function worked correctly before importing data from the server

Thnx a lot!

On screenshots you can see how it worked from the local file

https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/jeqxm50L/4/ errors code

Attempted import error: 'detailProduct' is not exported from '../dataProduct'.

Attempted import error: 'storeProducts' is not exported from '../data'.

Thnks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure where this is in your code, would recommend uploading code rather than image next time :)

In answer to your question you can assign it to a variable like so:

```
const response = fetch(“someurl”).then(data => data)
```

Or you could even set it to the state:

```
const response = fetch(“someurl”).then(data => data)

setState({ response})
```

You can then retrieve this by doing:

```
this.state.response
```

Try using a for loop instead of a for each:

```
for(var i = 0,  len = response.length; i < len; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks!   the import problem was solved but now throws the following error

https://jsfiddle.net/constant101/jeqxm50L/

Comment: Can you add the details here? Js fiddle isn’t working as I’m on my phone :)

Comment: It is strange that everything worked correctly from the local file. 
loaded data is displayed in the console.

Comment: Here's an error : TypeError: _data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.storeProducts.forEach is not a function. 
and it comes from the file which just imported data.js(fetch all products) and dataProduct(fetching only one product)

Comment: I will try to change my main post for clarity

Comment: You probably need to await the fetch request I assume - hard to tell with out all of the code :)

Comment: You do well blindly)

Comment: I changed my post for more info

Comment: Try changing to a for loop:

Comment: looks like i need to use JSON.parse here : fetch('https://yalantis-react-school.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products/4423b750-48ea-424a-9432-c77261bb4682')
.then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res)); or here : storeProducts.forEach(item => tempProducts.push({ ...item }));


but i don't know where exactly

Comment: for(var i = 0,  len = storeProducts.length; i < len; i++) {
  storeProducts.getJSONObject(i);
  tempProducts.push(i);
}
but console.log(tempProducts) still empty array
p.s. error gone

Comment: also Object.keys(storeProducts).forEach(item => tempProducts.push({ ...item }));
does not cause errors, but also does not return data

Comment: It's quite diffcult to help debug it without seeing the full project, so im not really sure where to go from here. My advice would be strip it back to basics and build up your component gradually :)